# mySQL80 Error 1045 (28000)::Access Denied for user@localhost (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, server, centos7

I have a fresh installation of mySQL80 on my Centos7 server but I can not access to mysql using the login.

When is queried mysql.user, 4 records found with same host (localhost) they are

- mysql.infoschema
- mysql.session
- mysql.sys
- root.

First 3 users have the same plugin (caching_sha2_password) and authentication_string.

Found some same related questions and followed the instruction provided but to no avail still can't login to mysql.

```
1. update the mysql.user plugin from 'caching_sha2_password' to 'mysql_native_password'
2. change the mysql.authentication_string to new password
```

[Can't find host '127.0.0.1 and '::1' not like the solution provided from other thread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiN7Z.jpg)

Comment: Are you using `root` as the username? Or are you using `user` as the username

Comment: im using root as the user.

Comment: Did you set a password on `root` as part of the install or not? If you didnt, there is no password on root so just leave it blank

Comment: Noo password during installation, can't log in without password. After installation, when I log in with skip-grant-tables, user 'root' has already have password from my previous installation.

Comment: Is there any way that this problem can be solve with *.ini files in the server? Maybe some line to edit i guess.

Comment: It sounds like you may have 2 instances of MySQL. How did you uninstall the previous version?

Comment: completely remove the mysql-server, move the mysql folder to mysql_old. reinstall the mysql80 but to no avail. Still can't login to mysql with the root temporary password. Even accessing the mysql.user table thru skip-grant-tables and changed the plugin and authenticatin_string

Comment: [link] (https://photos.app.goo.gl/FzsLHKRvXsyygnb5A) this is image of my user table with just 4 records. I can't find hosts - 127.0.0.1 and ::1.